# Draw JPanel into JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have two classes that extend JPanel: MapPanel and CityPanel. I am trying to draw a CityPanel into a MapPanel but nothing appears. I do not understand why if I add a JButton in the same way it will be displayed perfectly.
Here's the code:

```
public class PanelMap extends JPanel {

    public PanelMap() {
        CityPanel city = new CityPanel();
        city.setVisible(true);
        this.add(city);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

}



public class CityPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public CityPanel() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Test", 0, 0);     }

}
```

**EDIT:**

I have this code in CityMap. It display the string but no the image.

```
public CityPanel(String filePath, int red, int green, int blue) {
        this.image = colorImage(filePath, red, green, blue);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 50, 50, null); 
        g.drawString("sdjkfpod", 50, 50);
    }
```

Comment: `@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }` This code is utterly pointless. All it achieves is to ensure that the method does exactly what it would have done if the overridden method was missing.

Comment: Since `CityPanel` does not suggest a size and `PanelMap` has the default `FlowLayout`, the city panel will be 0x0 pixels and will not show up. Add a red `LineBorder` to it, to prove it to yourself More generally: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: give size to your inner panel...

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson do you see any problem with my answer?

Comment: Hi @Jean-BaptisteYunès could you please look at my answer and tell me any incorrect information that I have used?

Comment: ensure that the filePath points a valid image and debug the code to see image is not null. i test the code with  adding setPrefferedSize to CityPanel, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please replace your following constructor of `PanelMap.java`:

```
public PanelMap() {
  CityPanel city = new CityPanel();
  city.setVisible(true);
  this.add(city);
}
```

By following constructor:

```
public PanelMap() {
    String filePath = "C:\\...\\city2.png";
    CityPanel city = new CityPanel(filePath, 0, 255, 255);       
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(city, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
}
```

and see the result?

Following changes have been made to your code:

- The statement `city.setVisible(true);` is removed since it is not
  required at all.
- The statement `this.add(city);` was indeed adding `CityPanel` to
  `PanelMap` but `CityPanel` took up very small space and looked as a
  very small rectangle. This is the reason the `BorderLayout` has been
  used.

Following `PanelMapDemo.java` adds `PanelMap` to a `JFrame` and creates an executable example.

```
public class PanelMapDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            PanelMapDemo demoFrame = new PanelMapDemo("PanelMapDemo");
            demoFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public PanelMapDemo(String title) {
    super(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(new PanelMap());
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 200));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 }
}
```

On my system when the original picture was:

[image]

Your `MapPanel` changes the picture to:

[image]

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Hi @user1315621 have you looked at my answer?

Comment: Don't neglect to `pack()` the enclosing frame.